# Matlab GUI: Selecting a number from a popup menu

Tags: string, matlab, user-interface, popup, double

I have a variable `d` of size `50 x 1` and class double which contains numbers. I am trying to include this in a popup menu in a Matlab GUI. I am currently doing this:

```
d = cellfun(@num2str, num2cell(handles.zRaw(:)), 'uniformoutput', false);
S.T2pm5 = uicontrol('Style', 'popupmenu', 'BackgroundColor', 'w', 'Parent',...
            T2vbox6, 'String', {'Choose a Number', d{:}}, 'value', 1);
```

However, any selection from the above popup menu using `str2double(get(S.T2pm5, 'value'));` outputs all the numbers into a single string variable. How can I output only a single number selected by the user through the popup menu than all the values present there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by adding a callback that uses both the value and string properties of the popup menu. Here's a working example:

Create a popup menu with a callback

```
T2vbox6 = figure();
handles.zRaw = [10,20,30,40,50];
d = cellfun(@num2str, num2cell(handles.zRaw(:)), 'uniformoutput', false);
S.T2pm5 = uicontrol('Style', 'popupmenu', 'BackgroundColor', 'w', 'Parent',...
            T2vbox6, 'String', {'Choose a Number', d{:}}, 'value', 1,...
            'callback', @someMenuCallBack);
 str2double(get(S.T2pm5, 'value'))
```

Then define the call back:

```
function someMenuCallBack(hObj,event)

d = str2double(get(hObj, 'String'));
val = get(hObj,'Value');
disp(d(val))
```

This will display the value selected by the user at the command line.

Comment: I was thinking more from point of view of changing variable types than this workaround, which of course works perfectly fine. Thanks!